# Where can I find tutorials for Clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I've been looking into using Clang for a tool. But the only "documentation" I can find is the Doxygen output, which is about as useful as the wrong end of an automatic shotgun, and the API itself is about as user-friendly as nuclear waste. It makes some reference to a programmer's guide, but I can't actually seem to find anything like that.

Are there any decent tutorials around the Clang C++ API?

Comment: "which is about as useful as the wrong end of an automatic shotgun" - lol, it was worth getting up today for this sentence. I'm certain, however, that you haven't yet seen the [official documentation of libgpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/libgpod/docs/libgpod-The-Itdb-iTunesDB-structure.html). That's even worse.

Comment: @H2CO3, Remind me never to force myself into a situation where I have to use that.

Comment: @chris Imagine me porting that Linux library to iOS. (And I did it!)

Comment: @H2CO3, I'm shuddering just thinking about it. Good job.

Comment: @chris Too bad it was broken by iOS 5, so I had to reverse engineer loads of iOS frameworks. Damn you, Apple.

Comment: If you expand on the type of tool I may be able to give concrete examples, i.e. AST analysis, Rewriting, code completion/syntax highlighting, etc.

Comment: None of the above. I'm actually aiming to link LLVM modules of my own, with C++ source files, as code generated by Clang- which mostly involves name mangling, and code generating.

Comment: Ok, Code generation is in the LLVM layer & I only have experience up to the Sema passes in Clang. Good luck :)

Comment: well its 2020 now and I saw that shotgun too.  However other answers below are definitely helpful points.

Answer (score 7):

I found the following information illustrative:

- [Commented tutorial code to setup parsers](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial)
- [AST Visitors](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/RAVFrontendAction.html)
- [Source of the Clang Tools](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTools.html)
- The tests in the source repo (llvm/tools/clang/test)

Though I also found the documentation tends to focus on the c api; libclang.

After reading some of the tutorials above most of the commented source code made much more sense.

*However* the code base moves quickly and I have found that there has been some refactoring activity with the latest checkouts from svn so the tutorials may need to be updated slightly.

Answer (score 5):

Best you can use is [Eli Bendersky's blog posts](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/tag/llvm-clang) on llvm/clang.

Answer (score 0):

I found [LLVM's programmer's manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html) to be helpful.